# Theme broke a small piece of functionality

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-bydesign

Before the site was reskinned, which is great by the way, there used to be an indicator that would appear up in the meta/review/chat area that indicated if there were edits needing approval.  This little bit of functionality seems to be gone now.  Is there anything that can be done to bring that back?  It made it easy to know when revisions were queued up needing apporoval.

Comment: Are you sure that there not just weren't any suggested edits when you checked? It seems to work for me.

Comment: I'm sure, I did not see an indicator of suggested edits.  The only reason I knew to go into Review -> Suggested Edits was because I saw a question with the edit link looking like Edit(0).  I haven't seen the indicator since sp.se theme had changed.

Comment: So you're not seeing one *right now*? I submitted an anonymous edit for testing, and I see the count in the header (on the main site) at this very moment.

Comment: no I do not, nothing shows up

Comment: I do see it when I go to Review -> Suggested Edits

Comment: Oh, d'oh, *headslaps myself*. I'll answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't directly, but indirectly, have to do with the new theme.

When a Stack Exchange site graduates, the privilege reputation levels change. During the beta phase, these levels are lower; at graduation (which obviously coincides with the new design), they are raised to their standard levels.

The suggested edit count in the top bar is part of the [moderator tools privilege](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools). During the beta, this privilege requires 2,000 reputation, which you had. On a graduated site however, this is a 10,000 rep privilege; thus you lost it when the site became a full-fledged one, since you do not have 10k rep (yet).